# In $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ and finite complement topology, to what point(s), if any, does the sequence $x_{n} = 3 + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ converge?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

In the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, to what point or points (if any) does the sequence $x_{n} = 3 + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ converge?  What about in the lower limit topology $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$?

I claim that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ in the finite complement topology.  Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$.  Then $\mathbb{R}-U$ is finite, which means that there exists $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $x_{n} \not \in \mathbb{R}-U$, i.e., $x_{n} \in U$.  Next, I assert that $x_{n}$ does not converge to any point in $R_{\ell}$.  Indeed, $x_{n} \not \rightarrow 3$ because the neighborhood $[3,4)$ is a neighborhood of $3$ such that there does not exist $N$ for which $n \geq N$ implies $x_{n} \in [3,4)$.  In particular, no matter how "big" $n$ is, there will always be an $x_{n} \not \in [3,4)$.

Comment: Everything seems right

Comment: What is $x$?  Are you saying $x_n$ converges to $x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant yes!